# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.replace')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I followed a tutorial to use React-Navigation, I got a problem when trying to move to another page. I get this error:`Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.replace')`

I searched here and on other sites but nothing worked for me.
This is the code I have:

index:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Root } from './config/Router';

 class Application extends Component{
   render(){
     return <Root />;
   }
 }

export default Application;
```

Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Home from '../pages/Home';

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen: Login,
  },
  Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigatorOptions:{
      title: "Homepage"
    }
  }
});
```

Login (when clicking the button here, the problem occurs):

```
  export default class Login extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  _navigate(routeName){
    this.props.navigator.replace({
      name: routeName
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <View style = {styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._navigate.bind(this, 'Home')}>
            <Text>
              Hello.
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `this.props` undefined?

Comment: How can I check that? sorry for stupid question, I'm new to react native and web in general.

Comment: You can check this by running `console.log(this.props)` at the first line of your render method, then inspect the trace in your browser log

It might also help to see which tutorial you were using (for context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html#react-navigation), you'll want to navigate using `this.props.navigation`, not `this.props.navigator`:

```
 export default class Login extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  _navigate(routeName){
    this.props.navigation({
      name: routeName
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <View style = {styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._navigate.bind(this, 'Home')}>
            <Text>
              Hello.
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working great now.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Comment: Is there a way to "kill" a view after moving from it? I tried adding "replace" but with no luck.

Comment: @JohnDoah you can check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241083/how-to-remove-or-unmount-a-component-in-react-native).

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  //Some code here  
}

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
     //Some code here
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', () => SimpleApp);
```

You should register "Simple" rather than "HomeScreen"