# Force unmounting on screen change

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I recently integrated React Redux and Redux Thunk into my application in the hope that it would better allow me to manage state across screens.

However, using my navigation library (react native router flux), when ever I navigate between screens I get warnings of trying to set state across unmounted components and I am not sure what I would even need to unmount in componentWillUnmount as no calls should happen after a screen navigation.

My question then is, how can I force unmount everything on componentWillUnmount? Is there something built into React Native that I should use? Or, in my navigation library?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font'

class CustomText extends Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
            'varelaround-regular': require('../../../assets/fonts/varelaround-regular.ttf'),
            'opensans-regular': require('../../../assets/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf'),
            'opensans-bold': require('../../../assets/fonts/opensans-bold.ttf'),
        });

        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    }

    state = {
        fontLoaded: false,
    };


    setFontType = type => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'header':
                return 'varelaround-regular';
            case 'bold':
                return 'opensans-bold';
            default:
                return 'opensans-regular';
        }
    };

    render() {
        const font = this.setFontType(this.props.type ? this.props.type : 'normal');
        const style = [{ fontFamily: font }, this.props.style || {}];
        const allProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, { style: style });

        return (
            <View>
                {
                    this.state.fontLoaded ? (
                        <Text {...allProps}>{this.props.children}</Text>
                    ) : <Text></Text>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default CustomText;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

And one of my screens:

```
import React from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as profile from "../actions/profile";
import {
  CustomText
} from "../components/common/";

class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadProfile();
  }

  renderScreen() {
    return (

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.3 }}>
            <CustomText type="header" style={styles.headerTextStyle} onPress={() => Actions.home()}>
              Hello {this.props.name}!
            </CustomText>
          </View>
          </View>

    );
  }

  renderWaiting() {
    return (
      <GradientBackground type="purple">
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FFF" />
        </View>
      </GradientBackground>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.props.isLoading == true
          ? this.renderWaiting()
          : this.renderScreen()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.profile.profile.friendly_name,
    isLoading: state.profile.isLoading,
    error: state.profile.error
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadProfile: () => dispatch(profile.loadProfile())
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerTextStyle: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontSize: 40,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginVertical: 50
  },
  basicViewStyle: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: can you share your component code

Comment: Have shared an example above

Comment: so do you want to unmount the current scene?

Comment: Yes. When the text is clicked it navigates via React Router Flux to the home screen and this is where I see the error that state is being set on and I should unmount these/cancel subscriptions in componentDidUnmount()

Comment: look at that link  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241083/how-to-remove-or-unmount-a-component-in-react-native